# Prism cancel navigation WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I've a navigation request like

```
regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", "Login");
```

and after I have to do some checks (like check on file exists) in the called view model. If the check fails, then I must cancel the navigation request. Please tell me how can I do this?

```
public LoginViewModel(IRegionManager rm)
{ 
    if(!File.Exists("PathToFile")) 
    {
        //cancel navigation
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a view cancel a navigation request in PRISM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494981/how-can-a-view-cancel-a-navigation-request-in-prism)

Comment: No, because the ConfirmNavigationRequest call occurs in the class in which I am making the request and not in the LoginView class

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `IConfirmNavigationRequest` in your view model to enable cancellation. In the `ConfirmNavigationRequest` method, pass `true` to the `continuationCallback` to continue navigation, otherwise `false`.

```
public class LoginViewModel : BindableBase, IConfirmNavigationRequest
{
   public void ConfirmNavigationRequest(NavigationContext navigationContext, Action<bool> continuationCallback)
   {
      continuationCallback(File.Exists("PathToFile"));
   }

   // ...other members.
}
```

Comment: I have a base class ViewModelBase in which I am implementing the IConfirmNavigationRequest interface. In the Login view class, I override the ConfirmNavigationRequest method, but it is called only when I make a request somewhere in the LoginView class.

Comment: @Clashko because your method isn't `virtual`?

Comment: @Clashko Can you please provide your base implementation and the `LoginView` implementation as context in your question?